# JQUERY combine 2 sloppy lines into one - with some type of JQUERY Evaluate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following 2 lines of code:

```
var minusID = settingID + '-minus';
$('#' + minusID).removeClass("selected");
```

How can I efficiently combine this into one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#' + settingID + '-minus').removeClass("selected");
```

Can't think of anything much better than that, but you shouldn't worry about that, lines-of-code isn't really a concern any more...

Comment: In fact, I would argue that readability (and thus maintainability) is a much bigger concern than number of lines.

Comment: I really don't think that this is any harder to read, and we don't have an extra variable hanging around that doesn't carry it's own weight. +1